# Solving integrals of combination of $x^2$ and $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: integration

How do I solve the integral:   $\frac{2}{L}\int^{L}_{0}x^2 (\sin(\frac{\pi x}{L}))^2dx$

The answer is given as $\frac{L^2}{3}-\frac{L^2}{2\pi ^2} $

I know one solve using integration by parts, but I was wondering if there formula one can use to simplify this .

Comment: Use integration by parts; many times.

Comment: You can use double angle identity then Feynman's trick to avoid integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

First it is easier to deal with this undimensionalized integral instead

$$I = \frac{2L^2}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi x^2\sin^2x\:dx$$

By double angle identity we get

$$I = \frac{L^2}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi x^2dx - \frac{L^2}{\pi^3}\int_0^\pi x^2\cos 2x \:dx$$

The first piece evaluates to $\frac{L^2}{3}$. For the next piece, replace $2$ with the variable $a$ and recognize that

$$\int_0^\pi x^2\cos ax \:dx = -\frac{d^2}{da^2}\int_0^\pi \cos ax \:dx$$

Which means the second piece evaluates to

$$ \frac{L^2}{\pi^3}\frac{d^2}{da^2}\frac{\sin \pi a}{a}\Biggr|_{a=2} = -\frac{L^2}{2\pi^2}$$

as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Linearise the sine: $\;\sin^2\frac{\pi x}{L}=x^2\frac 12\bigl(1-\cos\frac{2\pi x}L\bigr)$, and use that
$$\tfrac 12x^2\Bigl(1-\cos\frac{2\pi x}L\Bigr)=\tfrac 12x^2\operatorname{Im}\Bigl(1-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi x}L}\Bigr),$$
to calculate first the antiderivative of $\enspace x^2\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi x}L}$, which has the form
$$(ax^2+bx+c)\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi x}L}  \quad (a,b,c\in\mathbf C).$$